# How do I store a MySQL query result into a local CSV file?

Tags: mysql

How do I store a MySQL query result into a local CSV file? I don't have access to the remote machine.

Comment: Then what kind of access do you have?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  "into outfile" writes the file on the DB serer, not the local machine.

Comment: Consider accepting @tmarthal's answer because it do saves result to local file.

Answer (score -24, accepted):

You can try doing :

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM table_name
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

We use the [OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html) clause here to store the output into a CSV file.
We enclose the fields in double-quotes to handle field values that have the comma in them and we separate the fields by comma and separate individual line using newline.

Comment: if suppose i dont have access in remote machine to store the generated file

Comment: You can use the mysql-client on the local machine, connect to the remote DB server and then issue the above query to store the result on the local machine.

Comment: Not sure how this is a solution, as the question specifically asks how to save to a local file, and INTO OUTFILE saves the file on the remote DB server.

Comment: I think this is not a solution at all. The question specifically says that the data must be saved locally, not remotely. Moreover, this is from the mysql documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html):

 If you want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server host, you normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file system.

Comment: Can you please remove this answer . Its been quoted in other places where user specifically asked for local setup and this was the answer and it misguides

Answer (score 60):

You're going to have to use the command line execution '-e' flag.

```
$> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u user -p -h remote.example.com -e "select t1.a,t1.b from db_schema.table1 t1 limit 10;" > hello.txt
```

Will generate a local *hello.txt* file in your current working directory with the output from the query.

Comment: if you save your query to a file you can alter this to: 
$> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u user -p -h remote.example.com < infile.sql > hello.txt

Comment: For me it only limits to 1000 rows. Is there a way to get all the data  ?

Comment: Best answer so far, but produces tab-delimited file, not CSV as OP asked for.

Comment: CSV is a general specification, it does not only apply for comma separated files. Every csv software library and spreadsheet program can handle different delimiters and different escape sequences.

Comment: Does it perform well when the result set is of magnitude 10 million ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the concat function of mysql

```
mysql -u <username> -p -h <hostname> -e "select concat(userid,',',surname,',',firstname,',',midname) as user from dbname.tablename;" > user.csv
```

You can delete the first line which contains the column name "user".

Comment: You can also specify the exact headings you want with something like: 

as 'userid,surname,firstname,midname'

Answer (score 3):

We can use command line execution '-e' flag and a simple python script to generate result in csv format.

- create a python file (lets name = tab2csv) and write the following code in it..

  ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import csv
   import sys
   tab_in = csv.reader(sys.stdin, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
   comma_out = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect=csv.excel)
   for row in tab_in:
     comma_out.writerow(row)
  ```
- Run the following command by updating mysql credentials correctly

  ```
  mysql -u orch -p -h database_ip -e "select * from database_name.table_name  limit 10;" | python tab2csv > outfile.csv
  ```

Result will be stored in outfile.csv.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to test it against content with difficult characters yet, but the fantastic [mycli](https://www.mycli.net/) may be a solution for many.

## Command line

```
mycli --csv -e "select * from table;" mysql://user@host:port/db  > file.csv
```

## Interactive mode:

```
\n \T csv ; \o ~/file.csv ; select * from table1; \P
```

1. `\n` disables pager that requires pressing space to display each page
2. `\T csv ;` - sets the output format to csv
3. `\o <filename> ;` - appends next output to a file
4. `<query> ;`
5. `\P` turns the pager back on

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem and I've been reading some time for a solution: importing into excel, importing into access, saving as text file...

I think the best solution *for windows* is the following:

- use the command insert...select to create a "result" table. The ideal scenario whould be to automatically create the fields of this result table, but this is not possible in mysql
- create an ODBC connection to the database
- use access or excel to extract the data and then save or process in the way you want

*For Unix/Linux* I think that the best solution might be using this -e option tmarthal said before and process the output through a processor like awk to get a proper format (CSV, xml, whatever).

Answer (score -8):

Run the MySQl query to generate CSV from your App like below

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

It will create the csv file in the tmp folder of the application.

Then you can add logic to send the file through headers.

Make sure the database user has permissions to write into the remote file-system.